# error Linking assets failed. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Error: Source and destination must not be the same

Tags: javascript, android, ios, node.js, react-native

I am linking assets for the purpose of using external custom fonts. The fonts folder is in `'./android/app/src/main/assets/fonts/'`. `'react-native link'` does not work but `'npx react-native link'` works, but with this error.

Would be great if somebody solved this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can i ask , what's your react native version ?

Comment: 0.61.5. The latest.

Comment: did you know after react-native version 0.60 , you dont need to any linking ?

Comment: Okay but the fontFamily thing should work right?....It's not working even now

Comment: Okay wait! It's working coz of some reason. I may have typed the fontFamily spelling wrong! Thanks for the effort anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just corrected the font name and it's working!